# Image reading as "undefined" by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I tested the below code for one image and it worked:

```
  let imageName1 = document.getElementById("the-edge");

  imageName1.onclick = function(element) {

    // Create the link to be copied
    hyperlink = imageName1.alt
    imgOpen = "[img]"
    imgClose = "[/img]"
    link = imgOpen.concat(hyperlink, imgClose)

    // Create a dummy TextArea to copy text 
    var dummy = document.createElement("textarea")
    document.body.appendChild(dummy)
    dummy.value = link
    dummy.select()

    document.execCommand("copy")
    document.body.removeChild(dummy)
  };
```

Now I tried to do this onclick for three images.

```
  let images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  console.log(images)

  for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      images[i].onclick = function(element) {

      // Create the link to be copied
      hyperlink = images[i].alt // THROWS THE ERROR HERE
      imgOpen = "[img]"
      imgClose = "[/img]"
      link = imgOpen.concat(hyperlink, imgClose)

      // Create a dummy TextArea to copy text 
      var dummy = document.createElement("textarea")
      document.body.appendChild(dummy)
      dummy.value = link
      dummy.select()

      document.execCommand("copy")
      document.body.removeChild(dummy)

      }
  }
```

Finally I got the error that `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'alt' of undefined`
 at the line `hyperlink = images[i].alt`.

But how can it be undefined? `console.log(images)` outputs

`HTMLCollection(3)
0: img#the-edge
1: img#the-rock
2: img#emma-stone
length: 3
emma-stone: img#emma-stone
the-edge: img#the-edge
the-rock: img#the-rock
__proto__: HTMLCollection`

I created a separate loop to store the `alt` before going onto the `onclick` section and it really is undefined, but why? doesn't the image have an `alt`? I've defined it so. And the first code worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs due to the context of counter `i`.

The value of `i` at the time the onclick is called is `3` and therefore the mentioned error occurs.

Another error is that the function onclick argument is not `element`, but `event`.

To access the element within the onclick function, you must use `event.target`.

The correct function is as follows:

```
let images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
console.log(images)
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].onclick = function (event) {
        // Create the link to be copied
        hyperlink = event.target.alt //EVENT.TARGET = ELEMENT

        imgOpen = "[img]"
        imgClose = "[/img]"
        link = imgOpen.concat(hyperlink, imgClose)
        console.log(link)


        // Create a dummy TextArea to copy text 
        var dummy = document.createElement("textarea")
        document.body.appendChild(dummy)
        dummy.value = link
        dummy.select()

        document.execCommand("copy")
        document.body.removeChild(dummy)

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Another way to do the same thing is as follows:

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
    <img alt='teste 0' id="the-edge">
    <img alt='teste 1' id="the-rock">
    <img alt='teste 2' id="emma-stone">

</body>
<script>
    let images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    console.log(images)
    // image is one item of images
    for (let image of images) {
        //image is used by reference here. on updating image, you are updating too images[x]
        image.onclick = function (event) {
            // Create the link to be copied
            hyperlink = event.target.alt // THROWS THE ERROR HERE

            imgOpen = "[img]"
            imgClose = "[/img]"
            link = imgOpen.concat(hyperlink, imgClose)
            console.log(link)


            // Create a dummy TextArea to copy text 
            var dummy = document.createElement("textarea")
            document.body.appendChild(dummy)
            dummy.value = link
            dummy.select()

            document.execCommand("copy")
            document.body.removeChild(dummy)

        }
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why is it `3` when it is time to call onclick? Shouldn't it be `0`?

Comment: The value of `i` is `3` at the time that the `onclick` is called, since the code within the `onclick` function is executed only when the click is triggered.

So much so that, if you observe, the error occurred only when the click was triggered.

At this point in the call to the `onclick` function, the `for` has already interacted `3` times to create the `onclick` functions of each image and the value of `i` is already `3`. So it is not interesting to use `i` into the scope of the `onclick` function.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Juliano. But the loops are still the same; the only thing that has changed is that we used `event.target.alt` now. Shouldn't `i` still be `3` in your correct solution?

Comment: Hi Jossie! In fact, the central point of the problem is the scope of `i`. If we print `i` inside the `onclick` function, whenever it is called it will print the value `3` and therefore we cannot use `i` inside the `onclick` function. This is because the code inside `onclick` is only executed when the click is triggered, that is, whenever `onclick` is called, `i` already has the value `3`. It is difficult to explain by text, is it not? kkkk

Comment: You are totally right. Why does the program work in your code then if i is still out of range?

Comment: Hi! Because in my code, `i` is used just outside the scope of the onclick function, to assign that function to a specific image. `images [i] .onclick = function ...`. This code will be executed during the loop and during the increment of `i`. Within the `onclick` function, I used the `event` passed as a parameter at the exact moment of the click, accessing `event.target.alt`. Note that `i` is not present inside my onclick function, just outside it.

Comment: I will edit my answer above by adding a second way of doing the same thing, perhaps it will help to clarify a little more.